Dockerfile ошибка при сборке проекта на Laravel
При сборке проекта, выдает ошибку
#17 2.144   0/98 [>---------------------------]   0%
#17 2.285  20/98 [=====>----------------------]  20%
#17 2.534  30/98 [========>-------------------]  30%
#17 2.753  47/98 [=============>--------------]  47%
#17 2.863  50/98 [==============>-------------]  51%
#17 3.042  59/98 [================>-----------]  60%
#17 3.358  70/98 [====================>-------]  71%
#17 4.256  80/98 [======================>-----]  81%
#17 4.729  91/98 [==========================>-]  92%
#17 5.712  98/98 [============================] 100%
#17 5.920 Generating optimized autoload files
#17 8.416 > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
#17 8.438 > @php artisan package:discover --ansi
#17 8.455 Could not open input file: artisan
#17 8.461 Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
#17 ...

#12 [node  1/15] FROM docker.io/library/node:latest@sha256:914458d8617650599ec2c05f6754403a1ce08cb471b0b1de1de439c539f8d45f
#12 CANCELED

#17 [composer_install 4/4] RUN composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
#17 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
------
 > [composer_install 4/4] RUN composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev:
3.042  59/98 [================>-----------]  60%
3.358  70/98 [====================>-------]  71%
4.256  80/98 [======================>-----]  81%
4.729  91/98 [==========================>-]  92%
5.712  98/98 [============================] 100%
5.920 Generating optimized autoload files
8.416 > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
8.438 > @php artisan package:discover --ansi
8.455 Could not open input file: artisan
8.461 Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
------
Dockerfile:4
--------------------
   2 |     WORKDIR /www
   3 |     COPY composer.* ./
   4 | >>> RUN composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
   5 |     
   6 |     FROM php:8.3-fpm as php_fpm
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

мой Dockerfile
FROM composer as composer_install
WORKDIR /www
COPY composer.* ./
RUN composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev

FROM php:8.3-fpm as php_fpm
WORKDIR /www
COPY --from=composer_install /www /www
RUN apk --no-cache update  && apk add --no-cache \
        icu-libs \
        bash \
        autoconf g++ make \
        postgresql-dev \
        ffmpeg \
        git \
        curl \
        libmemcached-dev \
        libz-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        libwebp-dev \
        libxpm-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        zip \
        unzip \
        icu-dev \
        autoconf \
        openssl \
        make \
        g++ \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd fileinfo xmlwriter tokenizer sodium session gmp pdo xml dom \
    && docker-php-source delete \
    && apk del .build-deps

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


# Этап 2: Установка Node.js
FROM node:latest as node
WORKDIR /www
COPY --from=php_fpm /www /www
RUN npm ci

# Очистка кэша в Laravel
RUN ./vendor/bin/sail artisan config:clear
RUN ./vendor/bin/sail artisan route:clear
RUN ./vendor/bin/sail artisan view:clear
RUN ./vendor/bin/sail artisan storage:link
RUN ./vendor/bin/sail artisan migarte

# Cборка фронтенда
RUN npm run build

# Кэширование Laravel
RUN ./vendor/bin/sail artisan optimize
RUN ./vendor/bin/sail artisan config:cache
RUN ./vendor/bin/sail artisan view:cache
RUN ./vendor/bin/sail artisan route:cache

#RUN php artisan key:generate
RUN chmod -R 777 /www/storage
EXPOSE 9000


Как бы очевидно что не понятно для находится этот файл? Вы путь до него где-то указывали?
